# open multiple pdf files in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

I want to open multiple pdf files on one click. I have different pdf files which are in for loop. But it overwrites the last file while opening.

```
$pdf_file = $this->load->view('/pdf/report', $print_info, TRUE);
echo $pdf_file;
```

I tried with body onload with `target=_blank`. but it's not opening pdf files in several windows.

Comment: May be you should make a div with unique id for per pdf into body and you can usr some javascript with div id`s onload function includes target=_blank.

Comment: but, the problem is I will not have URL. Because I am opening the pdf file after form submit (POST variables).

Comment: Can you please share more details about your form post and javascript also.

Comment: did you try it with target=_newtab instead of _blank

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding correctly, but this is what an array would be for.

`$pdfs = array();`
`$pdfs[] = $this->load->view(...);`

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="open_links()">Open PDF Files</a>
```

The JS:

```
function open_links(){
    window.open('http://test.com/pdf/1.pdf');
    window.open('http://test.com/pdf/2.pdf');
}
```

If the request needs to be sent before you get the URLs, then Ajax might be needed. Either way, you're probably going to end up with a messy solution.